# Pass arrays between VB.NET and VC++

Tags: c++, arrays, vb.net, matrix, pearson-correlation

I've a written a function to calculate the **correlation matrix** for variables (risks) held in a flat file structure. I.e. RiskID | Year | Amount

I have written the function because the library routines that I can find necessitate a matrix input.  That is, RiskID as 2nd dimension and year as the 1st dimension - with amounts as actual array values. The matrix needs to be complete, in that zero values must be included also and hence for sparsely populated non zero data - this leads to wasted iterations which can be bypassed.  The routine relies upon the data being sorted first by Year (asc) then by RiskID (asc)

I have written the routine in C++ (for speed) to be compiled as a dll and referenced in VB.NET.  I need to pass 3 arrays (one each for each of the headers) and return a 2 dimensional array back to VB.NET.  I guess I'm cheating by passing 3 individual 1d arrays instead of a 2d array but there you go.  I'll post the full C++ routine as others may find it useful if seeking to do something similar.  I'd be surprised if this hasn't been done before - but I just can't find it.

I lack the interop knowledge to implement this properly and am getting nowhere googling around.  As far as I can workout I may need to use SAFEARRAY ?
Or is there a quick fix to this problem?  Or is SAFEARRAY a piece of cake.  Either way an example would be very helpful.

Also, as a side note - I'm sure the memory management is failing somewhere?

**Here is the Visual C++ (VS2013)**

Header File

```
#ifndef CorrelLib_EXPORTS
#define CorrelLib_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define CorrelLib_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

// Returns correlation matrix for values in flat file
extern "C" CorrelLib_API double** __stdcall CalcMatrix(int* Risk, int* Year, double* Loss, const int& RowNo, const int& RiskNo, const int& NoSimYear);
```

CPP File

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CorrelLib.h"
#include <memory>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

extern "C" CorrelLib_API double** __stdcall CalcMatrix(int* Risk, int* Year, double* Loss, const int& RowNo, const int& RiskNo, const int& NoSimYear)
{
int a, b;
int i, j, k;
int YearCount, MissingYears;
int RowTrack;
//Relies on Year and Risk being sorted in ascending order in those respective orders Year asc, Risk asc
double *RiskTrack = new double[RiskNo](); //array of pointers?
int *RiskTrackBool = new int[RiskNo](); //() sets inital values to zero
double *RiskAvg = new double[RiskNo]();
double *RiskSD = new double[RiskNo]();
//Create 2d array to hold results 'array of pointers to 1D arrays of doubles'
double** Res = new double*[RiskNo];
for (i = 0; i < RiskNo; ++i)
{
    Res[i] = new double[RiskNo](); //()sets initial values to zero
}


//calculate average
for (i = 0; i < RowNo; i++)
{
    a = Risk[i];
    RiskAvg[a] = RiskAvg[a] + Loss[i];
}

for (i = 0; i < RiskNo; i++)
{
    RiskAvg[i] = RiskAvg[i] / NoSimYear;
}

//Enter Main Loop
YearCount = 0;
i = 0; //start at first row
do {
    YearCount = YearCount + 1;
    a = Risk[i];
    RiskTrack[a] = Loss[i] - RiskAvg[a];
    RiskTrackBool[a] = 1;

    j = i + 1;
    do
    {
        if (Year[j] != Year[i])
        {
            break;
        }
        b = (int)Risk[j];
        RiskTrack[b] = Loss[j] - RiskAvg[b];
        RiskTrackBool[b] = 1;
        j = j + 1;
    } while (j < RowNo);

    RowTrack = j;

    //check through RiskTrack and if no entry set to 0 - avg
    for (j = 0; j < RiskNo; j++)
    {
        if (RiskTrackBool[j] == 0)
        {
            RiskTrack[j] = -1.0 * RiskAvg[j];
            RiskTrackBool[j] = 1;
        }
    }

    //Now loop through and perform calcs
    for (j = 0; j < RiskNo; j++)
    {
        //SD
        RiskSD[j] = RiskSD[j] + RiskTrack[j] * RiskTrack[j];
        //Covar
        for (k = j + 1; k < RiskNo; k++)
        {
            Res[j][k] = Res[j][k] + RiskTrack[j] * RiskTrack[k];
        }
    }

    //Reset RiskTrack
    for (k = 0; k<RiskNo; k++)
    {
        RiskTrack[k] = 0.0;
        RiskTrackBool[k] = 0;
    }

    i = RowTrack;
} while (i < RowNo);

//Account For Missing Years
MissingYears = NoSimYear - YearCount;

for (i = 0; i < RiskNo; i++)
{
    //SD
    RiskSD[i] = RiskSD[i] + MissingYears * RiskAvg[i] * RiskAvg[i];
    //Covar
    for (j = i + 1; j < RiskNo; j++)
    {
        Res[i][j] = Res[i][j] + MissingYears * RiskAvg[i] * RiskAvg[j];
    }
}

//Covariance Matrix
for (i = 0; i < RiskNo; i++)
{
    //SD
    RiskSD[i] = sqrt(RiskSD[i] / (NoSimYear - 1));
    if (RiskSD[i] == 0.0)
    {
        RiskSD[i] = 1.0;
    }
    //Covar
    for (j = i + 1; j < RiskNo; j++)
    {
        Res[i][j] = Res[i][j] / (NoSimYear - 1);
    }
}

//Correlation Matrix
for (i = 0; i < RiskNo; i++)
{
    Res[i][i] = 1.0;
    for (j = i + 1; j < RiskNo; j++)
    {
        Res[i][j] = Res[i][j] / (RiskSD[i] * RiskSD[j]);
    }
}

//Clean up
delete[] RiskTrack;
delete[] RiskTrackBool;
delete[] RiskAvg;
delete[] RiskSD;

//Return Array
return Res;
}
```

Def File

```
LIBRARY CorrelLib

EXPORTS
CalcMatrix
```

**VB.NET**

I've created a simple winform with a button which triggers the code below.  I wish to link to the dll, pass the arrays and receive the result as a 2d array.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
<DllImport("CorrelLib.dll", EntryPoint:="CalcMatrix", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function CorrelMatrix2(ByRef Risk_FE As Integer, ByRef Year_FE As Integer, ByRef Loss_FE As Double, _
                                    ByRef RowNo As Long, ByRef RiskNo As Long, ByRef NoSimYear As Long) As Double(,)
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim Risk() As Long, Year() As Long, Loss() As Double
    Dim NoRisks As Long, NoSimYear As Long, NoRows As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim Result(,) As Double

    NoRisks = 50
    NoSimYear = 10000
    NoRows = NoRisks * NoSimYear

    ReDim Risk(0 To NoRows - 1), Year(0 To NoRows - 1), Loss(0 To NoRows - 1)

    counter = 0
    For i = 1 To NoSimYear
        For j = 1 To NoRisks
            Risk(counter) = j
            Year(counter) = i
            Loss(counter) = CDbl(Math.Floor((1000000 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1
            counter = counter + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    Dim dllDirectory As String = "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CorrelLibTestForm"
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + dllDirectory)

    Result = CorrelMatrix2(Risk(1), Year(1), Loss(1), NoRows, NoRisks, NoSimYear)
End Sub
End Class
```

Current Error Message

> An unhandled exception of type >'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in >CorrelLibTestForm.exe
>
> Additional information: Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid >managed/unmanaged type combination.

Answer (score 0):

A `double **` pointer to a pointer is **not** the same with a 2 dimension array in vb. Your best bet is to return just a pointer:

```
double *pdbl;
pdbl = &res[0][0];

return pdbl; //pdbl points to the first element
```

In vb you use an `IntPtr` to get the pointer:

```
Dim Result As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4)
Dim dbl As Double

Result = CorrelMatrix2(Risk(1), Year(1), Loss(1), NoRows, NoRisks, NoSimYear)

//derefference the double pointer, i(integer) is actually the index in the array of doubles 
dbl = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr.Add(Result, i * 8), GetType(Double)), Double)
```

Your `res` array in c++ function **needs** to be public so the memory allocated to it is valid after the function returns.